# Exit gracefully from glibc detected - malloc(): memory corruption

Tags: c++, signals

Is there a graceful way to recover from the following in C++?

```
\*** glibc detected *** glibc detected - malloc(): memory corruption **\*
```

I know that `try` / `catch` won't work and it does not seem like using `signal` handlers will work either.

Comment: I think the best way would be to find the broken code and fix it.

Comment: have you tried catching SIGSEGV (signal n°11) ? Is there a specific reason why you would want to "exit gracefully" ? Those kind of error should rarely be handled. Most of the time you should debug those kind of error post-mortem (and leave the program crash when they are encountered).

Comment: By the time you've got memory corruption, it is probably too late to recover gracefully. Even if you were able to catch and exception or handle a signal, there's no guarantee that the application's state is in any way sane or useable.

Comment: I agree with all of the comments above. The application is calling an external library that I can not modify. There are rare situations where invalid memory is accessed. Turns out catching SIGSEGV does work

Answer (score 0):

Catching `SIGSEGV` will prevent abrupt termination of the application. From there I can print a message and exit gracefully.